# Struggling with OpenLDAP configuration (on AWS EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ldap, openldap, access-control, phpldapadmin

I've been configurating a LDAP server on a linux instance using AWS EC2.
Up to now, I successfully set up LDAP and phpLDAPadmin to work together.

I've created Users and Groups "Organisation Units". I've added users and groups to those "OU"s.
Now I want to grand access to specific parts of my LDAP tree to the "Users" members of a "Group". That's what I wasn't able to configure up to now...

My LDAP tree looks like this:

```
+--> dc=www,dc=website,dc=com (3)
  ---> cn=admin
  +--> ou=groups (4)
  | ---> cn=admin_users
  | ---> cn=app1_users
  | ---> cn=app2_users
  | ---> cn=basic_users
  +--> ou=users (3)
  | ---> cn=user1
  | ---> cn=user2
  | ---> cn=user3
```

Let's say that I added user1 + user2 to the "memberUid" list of "app1_users" and user2 + user3 to the "memberUid" list of "app2_users".

I want:

- cn=admin have full rights/access to the tree
- app1_users can connect (to phpLDAPadmin) and add new members to the the group itself
- the same for app2_users' users

A connected user (on phpLDAPadmin) should only see the tree (and child substrees) he's part of.

Here are the ACI I tried (but whose were obsiouvly not working):

```
access to attrs=shadowLastChange
    by self write
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by * read

access to attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by anonymous auth by * none

access to dn.base=""
    by * read

access to dn.subtree="cn=app1_users,ou=groups,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com"
    by group.base="cn=app1_users,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write 
    by * none

access to dn.subtree="cn=app2_users,ou=groups,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com"
    by group.base="cn=app2_users,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write 
    by * none

access to *
    by self write
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write
    by * read
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

If `cn=admin,...` is your rootDn, it has all the rights there are and shouldn't be addressed in your own access rules.

For group management try:

`access to dn.base="cn=app1_users,ou=groups,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com"
    by group.exact="cn=app1_users,dc=www,dc=website,dc=com" write`

There's an implicit last rule `access to * by * none`, so no need for `by * none` in your own rules.

Generally, add your rules one by one to the list - it's easier to watch the effects that way.